# Including a case by subquery and excluding it gives different number of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query to determine if someone's a minor.

```
select 
case when 
((select trunc((sysdate - to_date(customer.birthday)) / 365, 0) from dual) > 18)  then 'N' -- If the age is greater than 18, not a minor
else 'Y'
end as minor,
-- other columns.....
from database.customer cusomter
```

The above query gives me around 100 results.
However, when I exclude that clause from my query like below, it gives me around 1000 results.

```
select 
customer.birthday,
-- other columns.....
from database.customer
```

I tried to look up the difference between decode and case by in oracle, and my guess is that it has something to do with how oracle handles null values, but I can't really put my finger on it.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If that's the entire query and there's nothing more you're running around it/with it/after it, that should not happen. Nothing in the `SELECT` clause should change which rows are returned by that same query block. You may want to search MOS to see if you have hit a bug. If however it's only a part of a larger query, we'd need to see the whole thing.

Comment: It cannot be as described because there's no `where`, `having`, `join` etc that may restrict the data returned. Please post the entire query

Answer (score 1):

You have the errors:

- The `cusomter` alias is misspelt.
- There are not 365 days in every year so your calculation will be incorrect and may say that someone is not a minor when they still are. Instead, you can find the number of months between the two dates.
- You do not need to query the `DUAL` table (it isn't wrong, just unnecessary).

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, birthday) >= 18 * 12
       THEN 'N'-- If the age is greater than 18, not a minor
       ELSE 'Y'
       END as minor,
       -- other columns.....
FROM   database.customer
```

> The above query gives me around 100 results. However, when I exclude that clause from my query like below, it gives me around 1000 results.

Whether you include something in the `SELECT` clause or not will not affect how many rows are returned; it is impossible that removing the `CASE` expression in the query above will give you extra results.

If you want to change how many rows are returned then you need to use a `WHERE` filter or a `JOIN`.